# C SHMGET returning values other than -1 on failure

Tags: c++, unix, shared-memory

I'm trying to create the equivalent to this Windows code with Unix Shared Memory, however instead of returning `-1` as the docs say and setting the `errno` value, when the shared memory hasn't been created yet, it returns 65537.

I'm just trying to get it to loop until the memory has been created in the other process and then return the id and 'connect to it'.

Windows Code:

```
    HANDLE hClientSlot = NULL;
    unsigned long long* clientSlot;

    while(hClientSlot == NULL)
    {
        hClientSlot = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, CLIENTSLOTNAME);

        if(hClientSlot == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Could not open Client Slot file mapping object:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    clientSlot = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>( MapViewOfFile(hClientSlot, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 1 * sizeof(unsigned long long)) );
    if(!clientSlot)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Failed to map Client Slot!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Unix Code: **EDIT: Added Key_T stuff based on @Zack's feedback**

```
    unsigned long long* clientSlot;
    int clientSlotID = -1;

    key_t slotKey;
    slotKey = ftok(CLIENTSLOTNAME, ID);

    while(clientSlotID == -1)
    {
        clientSlotID = shmget(slotKey, sizeof(unsigned long long), 0666);
    }

    clientSlot = (unsigned long long*) shmat(clientSlotID, NULL, 0);

    if(!clientSlot)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Failed to map client slot!" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: 1) What's the definition of `CLIENTSLOTNAME`?  2) Investigate `ftok`.  3) Are you *sure* `shmget` is failing?  Might it perhaps be *succeeding* but returning a handle to the wrong segment? 4) You may find the `shm_open` API more congenial.

Comment: `#define CLIENTSLOTNAME 4` Do I have to explicitly create a key_t variable and use that instead?

Comment: Oh and the windows version is `#define CLIENTSLOTNAME "Local\\ClientSlot"` Not that that is relevant but just in case you were wondering why that was working.

Comment: I've even changed everything to use shm_open and it still doesn't 'poll' as I want it to. Just grabs 'random' locations in memory :/

Comment: don't mix C and C++, these are two different languages

Comment: Why change the tag when my problems are with C functions and not C++?